# setdiff among 2 vectors 1st vector vs each element of 2nd vector

Tags: matlab, vectorization, logical-operators

I have 2 vectors let us say A=[1 2 3 4] and B=[1 2 4]. Using a for loop I can compute setdiff of A with each element of B. Giving the following vectors C1=[2 3 4], C2=[1 3 4], C3=[1 2 3].

Is there a way to achieve this in a vectorized form avoiding any for loop to get a Matrix M=[2 3 4;1 3 4;1 2 3]?

Comment: Can you safely assume each element of `B` is present in `A` exactly once?

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible for cases similar to your example

```
A=[1 2 3 4]
B=[1 2 4]
intrim=repmat(A.',1,numel(B))
M=reshape(intrim(B~=A.'),[],numel(B)).'
```

produces

```
M =

     2     3     4
     1     3     4
     1     2     3
```

It could even be squeezed into an one-liner with *subsref*, if that's your thing.

But further generalizing (e.g. if both set after expansion still contains multiple elements) might be challenging.

Comment: Note this is subtly different to doing a `setdiff`, as you're assuming each element of `B` is present exactly once in `A`, and you don't change the sort order. This might be the case for the OP, but using `setdiff` as in the question it would be possible to get outputs of different lengths if values in `A` were repeated or not in `B`, and by default the outputs of `setdiff` are sorted (this example is already, but arbitrary examples might not be)